# Iterator validity with ordered maps

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I have a map definition and subsequent manipulation like this.

```
map<int,string> m;
m.insert(std::pair<int,string>(1,"A");
m.insert(std::pair<int,string>(2,"B");
m.insert(std::pair<int,string>(3,"C");
m.insert(std::pair<int,string>(4,"D");
auto it = m.find(2);
m.erase(m.find(3));
cout<< it->second;
```

Will "it" be valid after an erase to some other element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will "it" be valid after an erase to some other element ?

Yes, [`std::map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) will only invalidate references and iterators to the erased elements.

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Note the code `m.erase(m.find(3));` has a potential problem, since [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) will return `end()` iterator if nothing is found, but `end()` iterator cannot be used with `std::map::erase`.

> The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()`
>   iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as
>   a value for `pos`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. Only the erased iterator is invalidated when a map erase is performed.